# QStateMachine immediate transition from dummy state

Tags: c++, qt, qstatemachine

In order to set an object property depending on a transition I need two intermediate states that immediately transition further:

```
   A       initial state
 Ta Tb     different transitions
 Aa  Ab    (these are only used to set an objects property depending on transition)
 TB TB     both should immediately "transit"
   B       objects property used via entered()/exited() signals
```

(Alternatively, B probably could be duplicated to set each respective property directly.)

Could a state's entered() signal be used as its own transition source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add an unconditional transition to the state:

```
TB->addTransition(B);
```

This is idiomatic and also cheaper than using a `QSignalTransition` coupled to the `entered()` signal.

Ref: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/statemachine-api.html#targetless-transitions

Comment: When would such a transition occur? 

It seems that it doesn't happen immediately.  Perhaps on the next QStateMachine internal event loop?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the QState's entered() signal can be used as transition source.